# What effect does `static` have on a method in a namespace?

Tags: c++

Does `static` mean anything on `func2` in the context of a namespace? Both methods appear to be equivalent.

```
// MyHeader.h
namespace TestNameSpace
{
    int func1() { return 1; }
    static int func2() { return 2; }
}

// SomeFile.cpp
#include "MyHeader.h"
// ...
int test1 = TestNameSpace::func1(); // 1
int test2 = TestNameSpace::func2(); // 2
```

Comment: what effect does it have outside of a namespace? same effect...

Comment: In a header file, a `static` function with an implementation is very odd. In a `cpp` file, `static` hides the function from the linker and therefore from anyone outside the file.

Comment: @user253751 Feel like that's misleading. "Outside of a namespace" could include "Inside the definition of a class", in which case the effect is actually quite different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`static` functions (which are not member of classes) are only visible in the compilation unit they are defined in. Apart from that there should not be any difference between those two

Comment: Minor caution: this is correct for static functions that are not members of classes. A static member function is completely different. +1.